# Cannot start Server service in Windows 7. Error 2: File Cannot be Found

Tags: windows-7, services

I'm having an issue when trying to start the Server service on my machine. I noticed that it wasn't started when I tried to access a share on my machine. I receive an error that states "Windows could not start the Server service on Local Computer. Error 2: They system cannot find the file specified." A snapshot of this error is below:

[image]

I've tried doing an "upgrade" of Windows to repair it, but the upgrade fails as it says I already have the latest Windows.

Any idea as to how I can repair this one file?

Comment: Look in the Windows\System32 folder for "services.exe", is it 32bit W7 or 64bit?

Comment: Scan for malware...http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1) [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)
- 2) [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-System-Restore)
- 3) Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to figure out what 'file' is being looked for when the Server service starts.

Comment: 1) Tried this and it didn't do anything

Comment: 2) No restore points available on this machine. I thought SP1 automatically took one, but apparently not.

Comment: Added 3. You should get a restore point at every windows update, unless you've turned them off, so that's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file "Srvsvc.dll" in C:\Windows\System32? I believe that's the file it's trying to use to start the service. If it's not there, you got some issue (virus or antivirus deleted it maybe?).